# Accessing WebBrowser on different Threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, browser

I want to access a static WebBrowser from different threads.

Here is my sample code:

```
public partial class MainFrame : Form
{
    public static WebBrowser webBrowser = new WebBrowser();

     public MainFrame()
     {
         InitializeComponent();
     }
}

class Job
{
    public void Process()
    {
        MainFrame.webBrowser.Navigate("http://www.google.com");
        while (MainFrame.webBrowser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Application.DoEvents();
        }
    }
}
```

For simplicity suppose I have 2 threads. Thread 1 calls Process() function and waits for it to finish, so at this stage webBrowser should be in Complete `WebBrowserReadyState` mode.

10 seconds after thread 1 is finished, Thread 2 calls `Process()` function. At this moment If i debug my code and put a BreakPoint at the first line of `Process()` function and watch `MainFrame.webBrowser` variable I would see this:

[image: Debug information of MainFrame.webBrowser]

In another words it's somehow inaccessible. Anyone knows any solution to this issue?

> Additional info: 10 seconds after thread 1 is
>   finished, If I call Thread 1 again, then everything looks fine.

Comment: WebBrowser is a single-threaded COM object.  Inspecting it from a worker thread does not do what you hope it does, it requires the thread that owns the browser to be running.  It is not, it got frozen by the debugger.  It also means that using a thread is pointless.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot directly call WebBrowser control's methods or properties from a thread the control was not created on. You'd need to proxy such calls into the control's parent thread. One way of doing this is with [BeginInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke.aspx), but it is asynchronous.

If you really need to do it synchronously, you could use [SynchronizationContext.Send](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.send.aspx), like this:

```
public partial class MainFrame : Form
{
    public static WebBrowser webBrowser = new WebBrowser();

    public static System.Threading.SynchronizationContext mainThreadContext = System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.Current;


    public MainFrame()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

class Job
{
    public void Process()
    {
        mainThreadContext.Send(delegate 
        {
            MainFrame.webBrowser.Navigate("http://www.google.com");
        }, null);

        bool ready = false;
        while (!ready)
        {
            mainThreadContext.Send(delegate 
            {
                ready = MainFrame.webBrowser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete;
            }, null);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            // if you don't have any UI on this thread, DoEvent is redundant
            Application.DoEvents(); 
        }
    }
}
```

Anyway, the above code doesn't looks like a good design to me. What are you trying to achieve? There might be a better way of do it. Perhaps, you can just use [WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted.aspx) event?